# PHP save data to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am new to php, I have brought a frontend template online html/css/javascript which generates new table rows dynamically, no I want to save all the data in this dynamic table in the database, but each time the form is submited only the data in the last dynamic row is saved and the rest of the table data is lost.

[image]

## **Java Script code **

```
const tBody = document.getElementById("table-body");

addNewRow =()=> {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.className = "single-row";
    row.innerHTML = `<td><a class="cut" id="cut">-</a>
                    <textarea placeholder="Product name" name="Product_name[]" class="product left "id="pro_name" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden; width:100%;"></textarea></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="0" name="price[]" class="price" id="price" onkeyup="getInput()"></td>
                    <td><input type="number"  placeholder="0" name="unit[]" class="unit" id="unit" onkeyup="getInput()"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" placeholder="0" name="amount[]" class="amount" id="amount" readonly="readonly"></td>`

    // tBody.insertBefore(row, tBody.lastElementChild.previousSibling);
    tBody.insertBefore(row, tBody.previousSibling.firstChild);
}

document.getElementById("add-row").addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    addNewRow();
});

//GET INPUTS, MULTIPLY AND GET THE ITEM PRICE
getInput =()=> {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr.single-row");
    rows.forEach((currentRow) => {
        var unit = currentRow.querySelector("#unit").value;
        var price = currentRow.querySelector("#price").value;

        amount = unit * price;
        currentRow.querySelector("#amount").value = amount;
        overallSum();

    })
};

//Get the overall sum/Total
overallSum =()=> {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName("amount");
    var total = 0;
    var Amount_paid = document.getElementById('Amount_paid').value;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].value) {
            total += +arr[i].value;
        }
        document.getElementById("total").value = total;
        document.getElementById("Final_Balance").value = total-Amount_paid;
    }
};
```

## **HTML code**

```
<form action="Create_Quote.php" method="POST">


<div class="invoice-body">
                <table class="inventory">
                    <thead>
                        <th >Description</th> 
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="table-body">
                        <tr class="single-row">
                            <td><a class="cut" id="cut">-</a>
                                <textarea placeholder="Product name" name="Product_name[]" class="product left "id="pro_name" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden; width:100%;"></textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="number" placeholder="0" name="price[]" class="price" id="price" onkeyup="getInput()"></td>
                            <td><input type="number"  placeholder="0" name="unit[]" class="unit" id="unit" onkeyup="getInput()"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" placeholder="0" name="amount[]" class="amount" id="amount" readonly="readonly"></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
 
                </table>
                <a href="#" class="add" id="add-row"><span>+</span></a>
            </div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class='Create not_to_print' id='do-create'>Create</button>

</form>
```

## **PHP code**

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  
        $invoice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['invoice']);

        $Product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['Product_name']);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['price']);
        $unit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['unit']);
        $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['amount']);

        $numberOfRows = count($_POST['Product_name']);
        for($x=0; $x < count($_POST["Product_name"]); $x++){

            echo $Product_name[$x]; // only returns the last item!
        }


        for($x=0; $x < count($_POST["Product_name"]); $x++){

            echo $Product_name;

            $query = "INSERT INTO products VALUES ('$invoice','$Product_name','$price','$unit','$amount')";
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
            if(!mysqli_query($connection ,$query)){
                echo 'Query Error: ' .mysqli_error($connection); 
            }
        }



}
```

Comment: You have no form element called `submit`, so your PHP code will never execute. Just check `if(!empty($_POST))` instead.

Comment: Instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you should be learning how to use prepared statements/parameterized queries. It's safer and the actually correct way to handle it.

Comment: `$_POST["Product_name"]` is NOT an array, you can't loop over it. You need to add the square brackets at the end of each name to make them an array (e.g `name="price[]"`). Then you will have to set the real_escape_string variables INSIDE the loop, using `$x` to identify the correct value for the loop

Comment: Each "row" that you add will all have the same name, which means the last row will override all the previous rows. You need to add `[]` to each name attribute to turn them into arrays

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and doesn't guard against everything.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but it only gets the last row of data. Here are my updates: 1. I have added the []in the name attribute name="Product_name[]", but this function $numberOfRows = count((array)$_POST['Product_name']); returns only 1 why is that? @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: If you have updates to your code, or other useful information, please [edit] your question, don't put them in the comments! See also [ask]. If you followed GrumpyCrouton's advice though, it's hard to see what could have gone wrong. Perhaps you made some small mistake. So yes, please update your question :-)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. But what you've posted in the question, and your description of it doesn't make sense, and you haven't followed the instructions. `echo $Product_name[$x];` cannot possibly produce a value _before_ $Product_name was even defined!

Comment: And you haven't followed the `you need to add the square brackets at the end of each name to make them an array (e.g name="price[]")` instruction - or at least, not in your updated code! And you don't need another `for` loop. The instruction was `set the real_escape_string variables INSIDE the loop, using $x to identify the correct value` . That means inside the already-existing `for` loop

Comment: `$numberOfRows = count((array)$_POST['Product_name']);` would return the right number of rows, _if_ your form actually submitted them - demo: https://3v4l.org/J4c07 . This suggests you didn't actually submit more than one row. P.S. You don't need the `(array)` cast...it's already an array

Comment: Now you've put the `[]` into the original HTML, but not into the matching HTML you generate via the Javascript. It needs to be present on _all_ the fields! (As an aside, this is a reason you should consider using a templating system in future for this kind of thing, then you don't end up needing to make the same change in two different places to achieve one thing)

Comment: Why does the form only submit one row? @ADyson

Comment: Because you forgot those []s. Now, if you add rows via Javascript, it should submit them all.

Comment: I made a demo using your latest code and it submits the data to the server correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/0qr7b1gf/ (check the payload in the Network tool). Now you just have to sort out the PHP code

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array

Comment: Hm. Please show the output of `var_dump($_POST);` after you have submitted the form with more than one row of data. As I showed in the JSFiddle link, it should submit it correctly.

Comment: [Product_name] => e3 [price] => 3 [unit] => 3 [amount] => 9, I only got the last value again

Comment: @HaidiElnagdy In that case I think there is a mismatch between the code you have shown here, and the code you are actually using in your HTML page. Because as I proved in the JSFiddle link above, the code you have now shown us here will correctly submit multiple rows of data to the server. Make sure you are not testing with an old / cached copy of the page, or something like that.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot, it worked after I cleared the cache. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I see you have nicely added `[]` to the `name` of the tags to be submitted in your edits to this question. You should really switch to PDO and work with parameterized queries, as several people pointed out in the comment section. Besides that, you will need to open your Dev Tools and go to the Network tab and see what is actually being posted during the request via the Payload. There you will likely see fields, such as `price[]`, `unit[]` and `amount[]`. If so, then you will need to add the `[]` to your usage of these fields in your server, a.k.a. PHP code.

Make sure that the name of the parameter that is being posted is properly received at the server. You can debug `array_keys($_POST)` as well (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to find out what the expected keys actually are.